# the queen fed her enemies to her dragons

Tags: terminology, figures-of-speech

In matters of government, we often say that a ruler did something when he/she actually ordered a bunch of other people to do something.  For example, we might say, "The queen fed her enemies to her dragons," when in reality she ordered someone to order other people to physically carry her enemies to her dragons.  We can see the same sort of phenomenon in more mundane matters too.  A newly published author might say, "I published a book," when the reality is that a company processed some paperwork and a factory physically produced copies of the book.

Is there a **special term** to describe these scenarios, in which a single actor is assigned sole credit for a complex action?  Something like *metonym*, but not exactly, since I'm interested in how we speak of the actor doing something that she couldn't literally do on her own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an example of **metonymy**:

> It’s metonymy when you use a person’s name to refer to the works by that person, as when you say “I had to read Hemingway for a class” when you really mean “I had to read a work by Hemingway for a class.” Another straightforward example is when you use a city’s name to refer to its team, as when you say “Houston was ahead by six points.”

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/synecdoche-metonymy-usage-differences)

Or possibly **synecdoche** (sources seem to differ in the exact definition of each):

> A figure of speech in which a part is made to represent the whole or vice versa, as in England lost by six wickets

[Oxford Dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/synecdoche)

Comment: Perhaps "metonymic agency" could be a full description, to indicate how the metonym is being ascribed responsibility for actions it can't literally execute?

Answer (score 0):

The soldiers, guards, etc. who physically carried out the enemies to the dragons acted as the **agents** of the queen; the queen was their **principal** (in one of the several senses of that word); the relationship between the guards and the queen was one of **agency**.  When such a relationship exists, the agent is acting **on behalf of** the principal. The principal has the responsibility for the action, as if he or she carried it out directly; the principal may thus be blamed, praised, sued, rewarded, etc. for the action.

Comment: But is there a single word to describe the phenomenon?

Comment: The word **is** *agency*. The phenomenon in question is not a peculiarly linguistic phenomenon (and is certainly not confined to English); it is a matter of legal, moral, and similar norms. We speak this way because this way of speaking reflects how we allocate responsibility.

Comment: I would argue that it is partially linguistic.  It's also not just about assigning responsibility; as in the case of publishing a book, it's also about omitting all the literal steps involved in a process.

Comment: The linguistic aspect is the difference between "*The queen fed her enemies to her dragons*" and the more literal "*The queen had her staff feed her enemies to her dragons*"

Answer (score 0):

In the absence of anything better I would suggest [attribution](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/attribution).

The Oxford Dictionary Online defines attribution as

> The action of regarding something as being **caused by** a person or thing.

or

> The action of ascribing a work or remark to a particular author, artist, or person.

The same dictionary describes the related verb [attribute](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/attribute) as

> Ascribe a work or remark to (a particular author, artist, or speaker)

With the example

> The building was **attributed** to Inigo Jones

The point of including the Inigo Jones reference is that, so far as I know, Jones never laid a brick but the design was his. By extention the sentences "William the Conqueror built the Tower of London" and "Edward the First built castles all over Wales" are also attribution since the kings did no building, and probably had no detailed involvement in the designs, because they were too busy doing other things. However the building of the castles was definitely **caused by** the kings.

Comment: Hmm, I suppose this could work. I was hoping for a more linguistic term, the antithesis of literalism, or something.

Comment: @artificial_moonlet I'm prepared to believe that there is a term that might be known by other contributors but I'm not going to hold my breath for one of them to post it.